# conntrack shows no result

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I tried the command `conntrack -L` and it returns `0 flow entries have been shown` on Ubuntu 18.04.
And `conntrack -E` doesn't display nothing.

I also tried to load the module by modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4, nf_conntrack, nf_conntrack_netlink.

Any one know what would be the solution?

Comment: As long as I have some iptables rule that uses state stuff, then conntrack works for me on 18.04.

Comment: Thanks. Once I set iptables rule as you said, conntrack works for me too. I wonder why this step is necessary on Ubuntu 18.04 not older version.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with the same problem.
The following iptables command can enable it，but I don't know if it has side effects.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That's not a "problem". Why should conntrack track connections when it's not required? By adding this rule you require conntrack to track connections and thus show items in `conntrack -L` output.

Comment: Also because the rule doesn't include `NEW` state, it doesn't have side effects and just enables tracking.